# Magento 2.0 after the instalation backend menu do not work

Tags: magento-2.0, adminmenu

The buttons do not work. It seems to me that are some incompatibility of missing configuration with the Browser. My site is in the localhost. I tried in IE11 and Chrome. In IE11 after have added my site into the compatibility view mode and the options of submenus appeared and worked, but without CSS.

I am beginner on Magento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Before that take **Backup**

Remove everything, except `.htaccess` file from `pub/static folder`

Open up `app/etc/di.xml` find the path `“Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink”` and replace to `Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy`

Note: Remove entire files and folder under `pub/static` except `.htaccess` file.

For More info ref this http://www.dckap.com/blog/magento-2-admin-links-not-working-in-windows/

Answer (score 0):

Run following command from magento root

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

For Magento 2.1.x and earlery

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Use -f for force deploy on 2.2.x or late

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```